# GroupBy site name inside my CAML query

Tags: development, web-part, caml-query, content-query-web-part, caml

I wrote the following CAML query to be used inside my Content Query Web part, but i am not sure if i can define to Group the retrieved item by site name :-

```
<property name="QueryOverride" type="string">
        <![CDATA[<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Created" Ascending="FALSE"/></OrderBy>
        <Where>
        <Or>
        <Or>

        <Or>
        <And>
        <And><Eq><FieldRef ID="{6937ba16-d8e1-4f57-b86f-232c4d193aa0}"/><Value Type="User"><UserID/></Value></Eq><IsNotNull><FieldRef ID="{6937ba16-d8e1-4f57-b86f-232c4d193aa0}"/></IsNotNull></And>
        <Neq><FieldRef Name="Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_status"/><Value Type="Choice">Closed</Value></Neq></And>
        <And>
        <And><Eq><FieldRef ID="{ac6b3e79-81af-477d-bf51-a9e3942bac6d}"/><Value Type="User"><UserID/></Value></Eq>
        <IsNotNull><FieldRef ID="{ac6b3e79-81af-477d-bf51-a9e3942bac6d}"/></IsNotNull></And>
        <Neq><FieldRef Name="Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_status"/><Value Type="Choice">Closed</Value></Neq></And>
        </Or>

        <Or>
        <And>
        <And><Eq><FieldRef ID="{ac8e7094-3a4e-44cc-931f-5538179f9823}"/><Value Type="User"><UserID/></Value></Eq><IsNotNull><FieldRef ID="{ac8e7094-3a4e-44cc-931f-5538179f9823}"/></IsNotNull></And>
        <Neq><FieldRef Name="Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_status"/><Value Type="Choice">Closed</Value></Neq></And>
        <And><And><Eq><FieldRef ID="{1bd27fec-5962-420a-8419-2af472812b28}"/><Value Type="User"><UserID/></Value></Eq>
        <IsNotNull><FieldRef ID="{1bd27fec-5962-420a-8419-2af472812b28}"/></IsNotNull></And><Neq><FieldRef Name="Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_status"/><Value Type="Choice">Closed</Value></Neq></And>
        </Or>
        </Or>
        <Or>
        <And><And><Eq><FieldRef ID="{fc42fea3-749a-4de4-8bcc-b77b790af081}"/><Value Type="User"><UserID/></Value></Eq><IsNotNull><FieldRef ID="{fc42fea3-749a-4de4-8bcc-b77b790af081}"/></IsNotNull></And>
        <Neq><FieldRef Name="Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_status"/><Value Type="Choice">Closed</Value></Neq></And><And><And><Eq><FieldRef ID="{fc42fea3-749a-4de4-8bcc-b77b790af081}"/><Value Type="User"><UserID/></Value></Eq>
        <IsNotNull><FieldRef ID="{fc42fea3-749a-4de4-8bcc-b77b790af081}"/></IsNotNull></And><Neq><FieldRef Name="Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_status"/><Value Type="Choice">Closed</Value></Neq></And></Or></Or></Where>]]>
        </property>
```

Now the problem i am facing is that when i upload this web part the Group By option will be disabled inside the UI, this happens since i am providing a custom CAML query inside the Content query web part.. so can anyone adivce on this? . in other words i am looking to have this effect inside my CAML query :-

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return a column containing Site Name within it, you can then:

```
 <GroupBy><FieldRef Name="**SiteNameField**" /></GroupBy>
```

Hope this helps